# How do you join to a .sql file as a subquery in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using Oracle SQL Developer, I develop queries that are copy/pasted as a subquery into a number of other queries. If I make a change, I have to go through all of the files and manually update those queries as well. It's very inefficient.
Is there a way of using sql files like programing modules? That way I only have to make a change in one place?

Comment: You can't. But you can program your subquery INTO the database. One way to do it would be a a VIEW

Comment: Agreed, you probably want to create a `VIEW`.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a stored procedure you can reference that in your queries and make the change in the procedure itself.